# Invalid URI for url using ? in python requests module

Tags: python, string, python-requests, escaping

I was trying to extract data using:

```
urlall = url+'/'+i+'.json'+'\\?'+'page='+str(page)

r = requests.get(urlall)

I got an error 400 Client Error: Invalid URI for url: the '\?' turned out to be '%5C?'
```

if I use:

```
urlall = url+'/'+i+'.json'+'?'+'page='+str(page)

Then I got another error: can only concatenate str (not "_io.TextIOWrapper") to str
```

How can I set '?' as a string and get only the '?' in the url instead of %5C?

Comment: try `str(i)` instead of `i`

Comment: A safer alternative is string formatting or a python library function @Shelly check my answer below

Answer (score 2):

You can use string formatting to create your resultant url ([string.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting) or [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/))

```
In [4]: url = 'http.example.com'                                                                                                          
In [5]: i = 1                                                                                                                             
In [8]: page = 1                                                                                                                          
#f-strings for python>=3.6
In [10]: f'{url}/{i}.json?page={page}'                                                                                                    
Out[10]: 'http.example.com/1.json?page=1'
#String formatting
In [11]: '{}/{}.json?page={}'.format(url, i, page)                                                                                        
Out[11]: 'http.example.com/1.json?page=1'
```

Or you can use [urllib.parse.urlunsplit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlunsplit) library to create your url, for example

```
In [1]: from urllib.parse import urlunsplit                                                                                               

In [2]: urlunsplit(['http','example.com','1.json','page=1',''])                                                                           
Out[2]: 'http://example.com/1.json?page=1'
```